# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'try' (T_TRY) in /customers/d/4/1/imanity.de/httpd.www/register.php on line 8

Tags: php, mysql

Hello so I followed a youtube tutorial as this is my first time trying this, now I got an error I checked everything and I come to no conclusion why it is not working to connect with the db.

```
<?php

 $server = 'imanity.de.mysql';
 $username = 'imanity_de';
 $password = '*********';
 $database = 'imanity_de';

 try{
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;", $username, $password);
 }

 catch(PDDException $e){
 die("Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
 }

 if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

// Enter the new user in the database

endif;

?>
```

Comment: This code has no such syntax error.

Comment: are you sure this is the register.php that is getting called

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you get the syntax error message as showed in title of this post? Your code looks fine, doesn't seem to trigger that error message.

Comment: I uploaded the error message to "http://i.imgur.com/282fylh.png"
also you could look up at "www.imanity.de" click on register and that error message should be shown....

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think I found my mistake, I packed everything in a folder called "auth" and I only uploaded the datas inside of it. Is it a must have to bring it into a folder called "auth" because then everyone has to put in "imanity.de/auth" into there webbrowser before accessing my page.

Sorry for the misstake and thanks for the help guys !